# k transfer function

Tags: control-system

If I'm giving a transfer function

$$T(s) = \frac{G(s)}{1+G(s)H(s)}$$

When calculating the critical gain using the routh hurwitz method and calculating a negative value for k. What does that tell you about the the system if k is negative?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See below Image,

[image]

Negative value of K will lead your poles on RHS side. Which makes your system unstable.

All coefficients being positive is necessary for all roots to be located in the left half-plan(LHS).

You can dig more at [here](https://www.facstaff.bucknell.edu/mastascu/eControlHTML/Stability/Routh.htm).

Comment: Do you mean the RHS?

Comment: Oh yes! Its RHS

Comment: are you able to understand or you still need more information?

Comment: for the most part. When I was calculating the critical gain using routh hurwitz I had the situation where: $$12 + 4k $$ what does that mean from there? k = -3 or k has to be greater than -3?

Comment: 12 + 4K is last coefficient or whole polynomial ?

Comment: it was in the first column for my routh hurwitz array located at s^1

Comment: Yes, Then you are right, 12 + 4K > 0, so k > -3 make your system stable.

Comment: I don't have enough rep unfortunately

Comment: just the check mark?